# Are transactions with an insufficient value marked as "failure"?

Tags: electrum, payment-processors

I have made a payment with an installed CardGate(curopayments.com) bitcoin gateway on a site, got a unique deposit adres, i sent a bit less than actual asked. The problem now is that the site owner says he didn't receive any payment because this occured.

Does anyone recognise this, and where is are my bitcoins?
[image]

This is a screenshot he sent of his CardGate admin panel

Comment: Are transactions with an insufficient value marked as "failure"?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Bitcoin.SE! This question is off-topic since it is a customer service issue. If you have record of a transaction being confirmed in the blockchain history (ie, a transaction ID, or at least a bitcoin address you paid to), you should show that to the merchant as proof that some payment was made.

Comment: @chytrik I did but they're declining they ever received something

Comment: @guest then consider them scammers

Comment: @Guest it may just be that the payment gateway is provided by a third party service, and the software is not built to properly deal with payments of incorrect amounts (ie, the merchant is not a scammer, they're just using crappy software). I would try contacting the merchant to explain things clearly and politely, and perhaps contact the payment software business as well to see if they can help out. There is nothing anyone here can do to help directly though, this is entirely a customer service issue at this point.

Answer (score 1):

> **Are transactions with an insufficient value marked as “failure”?**

No.

The blockchain, other nodes and miners have no idea how much the recipient is expecting to receive.

If your wallet and [blockchain explorers](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer) show the transaction as being confirmed then the recipient has received your money. It is now under their exclusive control.

> **the site owner says he didn't receive any payment**

Either they are confused or they are trying to deceive you.